# Android Studio: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: android, in-app-billing, aidl

I'm working on an application. It has 'in app purchasing' which I am creating with the help of online tutorial. But right now I'm having this problem. For which I have searched a lot in the steak overflow. But the problem is not being solved. please! Tell me where I'm wrong. I have also updated almost all the libraries. gradle version and API are also the latest. But there is still a problem.

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion '32.1.0-rc1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.breakbounce.balljump"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: 'YOUR_ONESIGNAL_KEY_HERE',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 32
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    // More repos here //
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:22.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation project(':aob_sessionreporting')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.6.0'
    // More deps here //
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.4.0'
}
```

in App billing service

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.android.vending.billing;

import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * InAppBillingService is the service that provides in-app billing version 3 and beyond.
 * This service provides the following features:
 * 1. Provides a new API to get details of in-app items published for the app including
 *    price, type, title and description.
 * 2. The purchase flow is synchronous and purchase information is available immediately
 *    after it completes.
 * 3. Purchase information of in-app purchases is maintained within the Google Play system
 *    till the purchase is consumed.
 * 4. An API to consume a purchase of an inapp item. All purchases of one-time
 *    in-app items are consumable and thereafter can be purchased again.
 * 5. An API to get current purchases of the user immediately. This will not contain any
 *    consumed purchases.
 *
 * All calls will give a response code with the following possible values
 * RESULT_OK = 0 - success
 * RESULT_USER_CANCELED = 1 - user pressed back or canceled a dialog
 * RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE = 3 - this billing API version is not supported for the type requested
 * RESULT_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE = 4 - requested SKU is not available for purchase
 * RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR = 5 - invalid arguments provided to the API
 * RESULT_ERROR = 6 - Fatal error during the API action
 * RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED = 7 - Failure to purchase since item is already owned
 * RESULT_ITEM_NOT_OWNED = 8 - Failure to consume since item is not owned
 */
interface IInAppBillingService {
    /**
     * Checks support for the requested billing API version, package and in-app type.
     * Minimum API version supported by this interface is 3.
     * @param apiVersion the billing version which the app is using
     * @param packageName the package name of the calling app
     * @param type type of the in-app item being purchased "inapp" for one-time purchases
     *        and "subs" for subscription.
     * @return RESULT_OK(0) on success, corresponding result code on failures
     */
    int isBillingSupported(int apiVersion, String packageName, String type);

    /**
     * Provides details of a list of SKUs
     * Given a list of SKUs of a valid type in the skusBundle, this returns a bundle
     * with a list JSON strings containing the productId, price, title and description.
     * This API can be called with a maximum of 20 SKUs.
     * @param apiVersion billing API version that the Third-party is using
     * @param packageName the package name of the calling app
     * @param skusBundle bundle containing a StringArrayList of SKUs with key "ITEM_ID_LIST"
     * @return Bundle containing the following key-value pairs
     *         "RESPONSE_CODE" with int value, RESULT_OK(0) if success, other response codes on
     *              failure as listed above.
     *         "DETAILS_LIST" with a StringArrayList containing purchase information
     *              in JSON format similar to:
     *              '{ "productId" : "exampleSku", "type" : "inapp", "price" : "$5.00",
     *                 "title : "Example Title", "description" : "This is an example description" }'
     */
    Bundle getSkuDetails(int apiVersion, String packageName, String type, in Bundle skusBundle);

    /**
     * Returns a pending intent to launch the purchase flow for an in-app item by providing a SKU,
     * the type, a unique purchase token and an optional developer payload.
     * @param apiVersion billing API version that the app is using
     * @param packageName package name of the calling app
     * @param sku the SKU of the in-app item as published in the developer console
     * @param type the type of the in-app item ("inapp" for one-time purchases
     *        and "subs" for subscription).
     * @param developerPayload optional argument to be sent back with the purchase information
     * @return Bundle containing the following key-value pairs
     *         "RESPONSE_CODE" with int value, RESULT_OK(0) if success, other response codes on
     *              failure as listed above.
     *         "BUY_INTENT" - PendingIntent to start the purchase flow
     *
     * The Pending intent should be launched with startIntentSenderForResult. When purchase flow
     * has completed, the onActivityResult() will give a resultCode of OK or CANCELED.
     * If the purchase is successful, the result data will contain the following key-value pairs
     *         "RESPONSE_CODE" with int value, RESULT_OK(0) if success, other response codes on
     *              failure as listed above.
     *         "INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA" - String in JSON format similar to
     *              '{"orderId":"12999763169054705758.1371079406387615",
     *                "packageName":"com.example.app",
     *                "productId":"exampleSku",
     *                "purchaseTime":1345678900000,
     *                "purchaseToken" : "122333444455555",
     *                "developerPayload":"example developer payload" }'
     *         "INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE" - String containing the signature of the purchase data that
     *                                  was signed with the private key of the developer
     *                                  TODO: change this to app-specific keys.
     */
    Bundle getBuyIntent(int apiVersion, String packageName, String sku, String type,
        String developerPayload);

    /**
     * Returns the current SKUs owned by the user of the type and package name specified along with
     * purchase information and a signature of the data to be validated.
     * This will return all SKUs that have been purchased in V3 and managed items purchased using
     * V1 and V2 that have not been consumed.
     * @param apiVersion billing API version that the app is using
     * @param packageName package name of the calling app
     * @param type the type of the in-app items being requested
     *        ("inapp" for one-time purchases and "subs" for subscription).
     * @param continuationToken to be set as null for the first call, if the number of owned
     *        skus are too many, a continuationToken is returned in the response bundle.
     *        This method can be called again with the continuation token to get the next set of
     *        owned skus.
     * @return Bundle containing the following key-value pairs
     *         "RESPONSE_CODE" with int value, RESULT_OK(0) if success, other response codes on
     *              failure as listed above.
     *         "INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST" - StringArrayList containing the list of SKUs
     *         "INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST" - StringArrayList containing the purchase information
     *         "INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST"- StringArrayList containing the signatures
     *                                      of the purchase information
     *         "INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN" - String containing a continuation token for the
     *                                      next set of in-app purchases. Only set if the
     *                                      user has more owned skus than the current list.
     */
    Bundle getPurchases(int apiVersion, String packageName, String type, String continuationToken);

    /**
     * Consume the last purchase of the given SKU. This will result in this item being removed
     * from all subsequent responses to getPurchases() and allow re-purchase of this item.
     * @param apiVersion billing API version that the app is using
     * @param packageName package name of the calling app
     * @param purchaseToken token in the purchase information JSON that identifies the purchase
     *        to be consumed
     * @return 0 if consumption succeeded. Appropriate error values for failures.
     */
    int consumePurchase(int apiVersion, String packageName, String purchaseToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api) had long been deprecated; use the `BillingClient` instead:

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:5.0.0'
```

For reference: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing